# Why does this map function not mutate the values in the original array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Here is the code in question:

```
const array = [
  1, 2, 3
]

array.map(item => {
  item = item + 1
})

console.log(array)
```

I thought that the `item` (first) argument in the `map` method is a reference to the original item in the array, and that mutating it directly would change the contents of that first array... is that not true?

Comment: If you want to *mutate* each item in an array, you would use 'forEach' and then call a mutating method on each element. When you do `item = item+1`, you're not mutating `item` regardless of if you call `.map` or `.forEach`, because you're just reassigning a local variable.

Answer (score 5):

Your array contains *primitives type* elements (integer here). Variables of type primitive cannot be mutated by its reference. Mutating is possible if for example elements of your array are objects, like below:

```js
var array = [{val: 1}, {val: 2}, {val: 3}];
array.map(item => {item.val = item.val + 1});
console.log(array);
```

Comment: So, you are saying that if that was not an array of primitive types, that assignment would change the original element?

Comment: Why would you use map in this way? If you don't intend to do anything with the returned array then you should use forEach.

Comment: @Jonah Yes, forEach do the Job but the OP is asking for map and want to know if mutations can appears with map

Comment: @Jonah You're wrong. the callback function's variable always refers to the original items in the array. If you change this variable, the original in the array also changes if it's not a primitive type, because of the reference. References are lost by reassignign by the code item = item + 1. For example, with objects in array, the original changes with map, like I show in the example of my answer

Comment: @Faly try this: `const array = [
  1, 2, 3
]

array.map((item,index) => {
  console.log(item);
  console.log(array[index]);
  item = item + 1;
  console.log(item);
  console.log(array[index]);
})`

You'll see that it does change the local variable "item" but does not change the actual element within the array. This is because objects, by default, are passed by reference, but value types are not.

Comment: @Jonah By doing item = item + 1, you reassign and loose reference. Even with object, if you reassign, you loose reference and the original is not mutated

Comment: @Jonah Take my example above and change it to array.map(item => {item = {};}); and you'll see that the items in the array are not mutated, because by reassigning, you loose reference to the original object

Answer (score 4):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function returns a new array, it does not change the original one.

`item` is a local variable here in [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `item => {...}`. The assignment `item = item + 1` does not change the original element, it rather changes `item` local variable.

If you'd like to change the elements `forEach` function is more efficient because it does not create a new array:

```
array.forEach((item, index) => {
    array[index] = item + 1;
});
```

Comment: OP doesn't care about the return value.  Imagine this code with a more complex object in place of `item`.  You could then do `item.someproperty = 1` - that's the question the OP is asking.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Can you overload `operator+` in JavaScript?

Comment: No.  And due to the way things are copied by value, `item` will only ever be able to be updated locally since it's a primitive.  If it were a more complex object, you could change properties on that object, but not replace it with an entirely different object.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I am not sure how relevant your comments are to this particular piece of code. You are discussing something else.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla says;

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

So, map function doesn't mutate values of the array.

I know you don't want to this, but you can use this:

```js
const array = [
  1, 2, 3
]

array.map((item, k) => {
  array[k] = item + 1
})

console.log(array)
```